# javascript toggle button inside php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating a status system on a project site I am building as a project to learn and get better at web development as I am a learner. I am pretty good at the php side of things but now I am trying to start a little learning in the javascript side of things and I am pretty stump on it to be honest.

I am using a php loop to get all of the statuses that have been submitted to the database and within that loop I am also getting all of the replies that have been submitted to each status.

I have a like system for the statuses and replies what is working fine except for the fact that when you click the button to like or dislike it, it doesn't disappear (because no javascript coded in) and because of this if you rapidly hit the like submit button (or dislike when php has run and has done its job) you can end up messing up the like count and it can go to minus or have extra likes because you are hitting it faster then the server can process and reload the page. I have it set that when you like a status you get put into the database as liking that status so if you do like a status php picks you up as liking the status and echos a dislike submit button instead of like.

I would like to stop this glitch because it isn't good pratice to have something what users can spam because for one they can mess up the count and they can also make a server run over time because they are sending loads of processes at once and if you had 100 or more users doing this at the same time the server will struggle with all of the processes happening all at once.

I can give each like/unlike submit button a unique id by using the id for each status/reply but will need to generate a js script for each status/reply that is created by the php loop.

This javascript works for a single button but doesn't work within a loop and it only toggles the 1st button because all the buttons have the same id and if I echo the php variable as the id for the button inside the javascipt then the javascript only works for the last like/unlike button on the page because only one javascript script has been written on the page.

```
function action() {
            document.getElementById('toggler').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
```

and the submit button to go with this is.

```
<input type="submit" name="status_like" value="Like" id="toggler" onClick="action();"/>
```

I am trying to make it so regardless how many like buttons have been echoed on the page the javascript only toggles the actual submit button that has been pressed what will stop the user from actually spamming that button because when the page reloads the button will be back to the way it was before they pressed the submit button.

In the future I will be looking into ajax to do the form submitting part for me but before then I need to get more practice with javascript itself.

I have included this jsfiddle link because it has my current code in there but for some reason it doesn't actually work in jsfiddle but it does work on my actual website page. I believe I am only including jquery 2.1.0 on that page and even when I include that in the jsfiddle it still doesn't work so I do apologize about that but once again that is because I am starting to learn javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/cuw9a/

I understand that using jquery will not help me to learn the basics of javascript but I do not mind using jquery at this moment in time because I understand that coding something like this may not be as simple as using jquery for the people that reply to this and that is why i do not mind using jquery to do this however if jquery is used then I would like it to work with jquery 2.1.0

If someone could help me out I would appreciate it very much

Thanks for your time

Comment: Do we really need all that information? Could you please provide TL;DR version if possible.

Comment: it seems ur fiddle is not working

Comment: I have written about it not working but the fact it works on my site. I am not sure why it isn't working in jsfiddle but is on my site. I only include jquery 2.1.0 on my site but having that selected in jsfiddle still doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @Molecular I have included all the information so you can understand what i am trying to do and the method I am using because if I didn't have all that information then there would be people what will read my question and give me an answer for the question as if I have not done a php loop and also some might not understand what I am actually trying to do. The question is long yes but i do feel it is all relevant and needed so you can understand exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: try this keyword to set the visiblity attribute for the corresponding element u are clicking

this.setAttribute('visibility', 'hidden);